# Using multhreading/multiprocessing to speed up loop accumulation, with shared resources

Tags: python, multithreading, algorithm, recursion, multiprocessing

I have been developing an algorithm to solve a Boggle board, [WebBoggle](https://github.com/shmuli9/WebBoggle). I have succeeded using python3, but I'm now trying to optimise it to work as fast as possible, and I wanted to use multithreading or multiprocessing to achieve the speed up.

The area where i think this could come in nicely is the `for` loop at the start of the algorithm which repeatedly calls the heavy-lifting function, like so:

```
nodes = [{obj1}, {obj2}, {obj3}, ... , {obj16}]
word_tree = {"children": {"A": {"data": "A", "children" :{...}}, "B": {"data": "B", "children": {...}}, ...}}

def doSomeWork():
    found_words = []
    for i in range(15):
        found_values += doHeavyLifting(nodes[i], word_tree.children["A"])
    return found_words
```

In this case the `nodes` array is static for the duration of the algorithm, think of it as read-only, and every process or thread can safely read it without worry's of race conditions or locking.

The `word_tree` object (hope its been portrayed clearly above) however, is modified by the `doHeavyLifting` function, but in segments, ie the `word_tree` has many `nodes` in it, and if a lock is required, it would be acquired on an individual `node`, not on the entire `word_tree`, eg the function might change something about node A, but it doesn't need to have a lock on node A's children (references to which are stored in node A's `children` dict).

Ultimately the return value of `doHeavyLifting` gets stored in the `found_words` array and returned when all `nodes` have been processed. (`doHeavyLifting` is a recursive function but I'm not sure that makes a difference for this question...)

I have never used multithreading in Python, and multiprocessing ever, and I was wondering how I would go about implementing this loop in a way that with 16 threads of CPU, every element in the `nodes` array can be processed simultaneously (or similar as appropriate given the system resources), and for the individual return values to be stored in one variable to be returned by the `doSomeWork` function.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you want each thread to run a search from a given place on the board.  The simple approach would be to let the threads run completely independently, and collect and remove duplicates at the end.  Or you could get the search threads to add batches of new words to the collection, every now and then.  The dictionary and the board are clearly read-only, so those can be shared trivially.  You will learn a lot just getting that to work.  After that, can you save anything by (a) eliminating duplicates earlier ?, (b) sharing common word endings between threads ?, (c) ... ??  But: start simple!

Comment: @ChrisHall , I have already made improvements like eliminating duplicates etc, the next step i can think of is threading

Comment: OK.  So what is stopping you ?  Folk here are happy to help with specific problems, particularly "I am trying this, but this doesn't work for reasons I don't understand".  Less happy to address general "how do I write this program ?" questions.  See: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As I said, you could partition the problem by giving each thread a starting location on the board and getting it to find all the words starting with that letter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What im asking is for the best overall way to achieve that. Some resources are shared safely, some are not safe and need locking of some kind. How would i go about achieving that with Python? Is multiprocessing the way to go as opposed to multithreading?

Comment: Absolutely: a big problem in multi-threading is what data needs to be shared between threads and how to achieve that safely.  Stuff which is not changed while some number of threads run, can trivially be shared by those threads.  Stuff which only a single thread reads/writes is also trivial.  I have suggested a "worker" thread for each start letter, to find all words from there, *independently*.  When a "worker" has all its words, it needs to add them to the result, using (say) a mutex to control access to that.  When all the "workers" have finished, the program can report the final result.